# .htaccess forwarding with new website

Tags: .htaccess, forwarding

A WordPress blog can be reached with mod_rewrite at http://xyz.de.
In the future this blog will be reached at http://blog.xyz.de. This is no challenge, however the old adresses have to forward to the actual article address.

http://xyz.de/YYYY/MM/DD/titel/ have to forward to http://blog.xyz.de/YYYY/MM/DD/titel/.

To make matters even more complicated, at the root domain ( http://xyz.de ) a new page have to be accessible.
This uses GET parameters for navigation. For example http://xyz.de/index.php?site=home.

Is there any way to realize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly trivial rewrite and redirect:

```
RewriteEngine On
# If the domain is xyz.de...
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz.de
# And the requested file is not /index.php (for the special case)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/(index\.php)?$
# Redirect to the new domain, appending any existing query string
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://blog.xyz.de/$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you!
However, when I go to http://xyz.de I will forward to http://blog.xyz.de.
Only if I type http://xyz.de/index.php I get the right page.

Comment: @JulianHinderer See the change above, to the second `RewriteCond`. I think that should take care of it